# how to get the max and min number in array?

Tags: linux

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "lets read an array "
read -a arr;

max=999;
min=-999;
n=10;

for((i=0;i<n;i++))
{
    if [ "${arr[$i]}" -gt "$max" ];
    then
        max=$arr[$i];
    fi

    if [ "${arr[$i]}" -lt "$min" ];
    then
        min=$arr[$i];
    fi
}
echo $max;
echo $min;
```

it give me an error
lets read an array
1 2 3 4

```
main.sh: line 12: [: : integer expression expected
main.sh: line 17: [: : integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 1):

You only enter 4 numbers, but the code expects 10 (`n=10`).

Try specifying `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` as the input, or use the actual size of the array instead of 10:

```
n=${#arr[@]}
```

There are more problems in the script (i.e. the initial values of `min` and `max` should have been vice versa, and assignment to `min` and `max` in the loop uses a wrong syntax, as you'll see after fixing this problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "lets read an array "
read -a arr; # any quantity

max=-999; # important iverse
min=999;  # important iverse

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    if [ $i -gt $max ];
      then
        max=$i;
    fi

    if [ $i -lt $min ];
      then
        min=$i;
    fi
done

echo max: $max;
echo min: $min;
```

**Console**

```
lets read an array 
1 20 3 25 7 14 65 4 32 17
max: 65
min: 1
```